# SQL ordering before select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table fields with `student id`, and `date of birth` i want to select oldest student from the table. I just want one student at time. I wrote this query

```
SELECT studid FROM student ORDER BY dob ASC LIMIT 1;
```

but it gives me another `student id`. How to fix this? How to Order table before select in one query?

I also tried `ORDER BY dob DESC but the problem` is same.
dob data type is datetime

Comment: should be order by asc

Comment: share the data for student you are expecting and the student being returned

Comment: what is the datatype of `dob` ? How values are stored in DB meaning which date format ?

Comment: data type - datetime

Comment: Then show some sample data. If the datatype is `datetime` then you should get the correct `student_id`

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result out of it.

Comment: i wanted to ask you is there a way to selecting data from sorted data not sorting data after selecting .

Comment: This problem solved by min() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT studid
FROM student
HAVING date of birth = MIN(date of birth)
```

Or

```
SELECT studid, MIN(date of birth)
FROM student
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
select top 1 studid from student order by dob asc
```